# How can you pipe a readable stream to another readable stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am doing exercises from the "stream-adventure", and I'm very uncertain about the `stream-combiner` module.

Specifically it says that:

> The `stream-combiner` module creates a pipeline from a list of
>   streams, returning a single stream that exposes the first stream as
>   the writable side and the last stream as the readable side like the
>   `duplexer` module, but with an arbitrary number of streams in between.
>   Unlike the `duplexer` module, each stream is piped to the next. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> var combine = require('stream-combiner');
> var stream = combine(a, b, c, d);
> ```
>
> will internally do `a.pipe(b).pipe(c).pipe(d)` but the `stream`
>   returned by `combine()` has its writable side hooked into `a` and its
>   readable side hooked into `d`.

Now as it says, "its writable side hooked into `a` and its readable side hooked into `d`", one can use the above `stream` like follows:

```
someReadableStream.pipe(stream).pipe(someWritableStream)
```

But won't the above just become:

```
someReadableStream.pipe(a).pipe(b).pipe(c).pipe(d).pipe(someWritableStream)
```

My question is how can a readable stream pipe to another readable stream. And at the end, how can the result of piping to a writable stream again pipe to a writable stream.

Comment: Have a look at PassThrough stream. It might be what you need.

Comment: @MattHarrison I guess you misunderstood me, my doubt is why the above works? :)

Comment: `a` and `d` would have to be both readable and writable.

Comment: So do I need to make sure of that? Or does it do automatically. Because the documentation on `stream-combiner` is like "does it even exist"

Comment: You need to write the readable contents of the stream, hence your second stream needs to be writable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a textual example that hopefully clarifies the rules about the streams in order for stream-combiner to do something useful:

```
var rw = combine(r_or_rw, rw1, rw2, rw3, ...rwN, w_or_rw)
```

So the first stream needs to be at least readable, the interior streams all need to be read/write, and the final stream needs to at least be writeable. The returned new stream is read/write. When you write to the returned stream, that sends new data down through the pipeline, and when you read that gives you data from the end of the pipeline.

Comment: I get the concept of combine, but I don't understand the fact that how come you can write data to the stream, since the first part of the new stream is a Readable stream

Comment: So if `stream1` is read-only, you won't be able to write to the returned stream, but if it's read/write, writing to the returned stream will write to stream1 and flow through the pipe. Similar situation on the end depending on whether the last stream is write-only or read/write. I think the stream-combiner API gives you a r/w stream for versatility but relies on you knowing the combinations that will and won't work.

Comment: That makes sense! Their documentation is really poor

Comment: Send a pull request! It's a tiny module. Open source!

Answer (score 0):

you are correct that it is the same as `readable.pipe(a).pipe(b).pipe(c).pipe(d).pipe(writable)`,
the advantage of combiner is that you cannot return `a.pipe(b).pipe(c).pipe(d)` from a function, so you must always manually connect them. with combiner you can create a stream out of other streams, and then tidy that away into a function or module.

for this to work, though, a,b,c,d all must be transform streams, that are both readable and writable.